# Error when trying to find minimum of java code with no known amount of integers

Tags: java

I have to make a code that takes in an unknown amount of user input integers, finds the min and max, and also finding the average of integers. This is what i have so far.

```
package HW2_Min_Max;

import java.util.Scanner; 


public class HW3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please input first interger");
        int number=0; //number is to store number of inputs 
        int i=1; //i is to store current iteration
        int sum=0; //sum is to store sum of the input 
        int x=0; //x is to store the user input
        int min=x, max=x; 

        number = myScanner.nextInt(); 

        if(x>=0)
            while (x >= 0){
            System.out.println("Please input the next positive interger ");
            x = myScanner.nextInt();
            sum = sum + x;
            number = number++;
            if (x >= max)
                max = x;
            if (x <= min)
                min =x;
            i++;
        }    




        int average = sum/number;

        System.out.println("The average is " + average);


        System.out.println("The minimum value is " + min);
        System.out.print( "and the maximum value is " + max);
        }
    }
```

It runs fine and does almost exactly what i want it to do, but the condition i gave it to end the program is basically any negative number. The output for max comes out right, but the negative affects the average and minimum. I can't figure a way to get the minimum to just end the program and not be entered into the values.

Comment: Add a condition after `x = myScanner.nextInt();` to `break` out of the loop if the number is negative.

Comment: You need to check the input **before** you use it to see if it's your exit condition. You can't use it and then check afterward on the next pass, or it's too late.

Comment: Also, you never need to do `if(c) { while(c) { ...} }`. The while condition gets evaluated and tested before every iteration, including the first one, do you can just do the while (without the if).

Comment: The problem is from the variable `number`. The variable `number` is what's holding the input/value entered and not the number of inputs as you said. This is because `myScanner.nextInt();` will retrieve value from console and assign it to number. So any negative value entered will for sure affect average but not minimum as you said. Just delete this line `number = myScanner.nextInt();`. That possibly should solve it.

Comment: @alfasin, I tried adding if (x<=0) System.out(0); before x = myScanner.nextInt(); to terminate the program once it detects a negative but it just completely ends it and does not execute the rest of the arguments. Can you clarify as to how to add a better condition?

Comment: @perry, I deleted that line but when I run the program and enter a negative number, it just ends the program and doesn't even print max, min, nor average.

Comment: @F.ochoa15 I wrote explicitly `break`, I didn't say anything about "terminating"!

Comment: @alfasin, sorry I'm still very new to Java, I did a bit more research and it seems that "if ( x <=0) break;" should work.

Comment: @F.ochoa15 doing research is good, keep at it!

Comment: @alfasin, after adding the break, it does end the loop and proceed to execute the next arguments. But it seems like my only problem is still getting the min and average to come out right, for some reason. Now what is happening is that the average is not being divided by the number of inputs, and the minimum is coming out as 0.

Comment: @F.ochoa15 I published an answer - hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting your min and max correctly:

```
int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE, max=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

which will ensure that the `min` and `max` *will* get updated.

Second, as  I wrote in the comments, bail out of the loop immediately after reading `x` if `x` is negative:

```
x = myScanner.nextInt();
if (x < 0) {
    break;
}
```

Third, start reading `myScanner.nextInt` only inside the while loop.

And last, get rid of the assignment:

```
number = number++;
```

change to:

```
number++;
```

because the operation `number++` doesn't return a value.

**Important**: It would be a good idea to learn how to work with a good IDE (for example: IntelliJ/Eclipse/Netbeans) and also learn how to work with a debugger.

Full code:

```
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number=0; //number is to store number of inputs
    int i=1; //i is to store current iteration
    int sum=0; //sum is to store sum of the input
    int x=0; //x is to store the user input
    int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE, max=Integer.MIN_VALUE; // fix 1

    while (x >= 0){
        System.out.println("Please input the next positive integer");
        x = myScanner.nextInt();
        if (x < 0) {  // fix 2
            break;
        }
        if(x>=0) {
            sum = sum + x;
            number++;   // fix 3
            if (x >= max)
                max = x;
            if (x <= min)
                min =x;
            i++;
        }
    }
    int average = sum/number;
    System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    System.out.println("The minimum value is " + min);
    System.out.print( "and the maximum value is " + max);
```

Running the code, I'm getting the following output:

```
Please input the next positive integer
1
Please input the next positive integer
2
Please input the next positive integer
3
Please input the next positive integer
4
Please input the next positive integer
5
Please input the next positive integer
-1
The average is 3
The minimum value is 1
and the maximum value is 5
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Currently am using NetBeans, but i'm still having problems. Seems that the only problem i have is still the average and the minimum. I did exactly what you told to update but when i input 1,2,3,4,5 as integers this is the end result. Please input first interger
1
Please input the next positive interger 
2
Please input the next positive interger 
3
Please input the next positive interger 
4
Please input the next positive interger 
5
Please input the next positive interger 
-1
The average is 2
The minimum value is 2
and the maximum value is

Comment: @F.ochoa15 I added the full corrected code. It works fine for me.

Comment: @F.ochoa15 This answer provided by alfasin should work for you. Well, note that variable `I` is just useless. Variable `number` can serve its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There was some issues in your code. First scanned integer value ignore in the calculation. And always min value is zero because 'int min = 0'
I did some changes on your code try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Please input first integer");
  int number = 0; //number is to store number of inputs
  int sum = 0; //sum is to store sum of the input
  int x; //x is to store the user input
  int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = 0;

  x = myScanner.nextInt();

  while (x >= 0) {
    sum = sum + x;
    number++;
    if (x >= max) {
      max = x;
    }
    if (x <= min) {
      min = x;
    }
    System.out.println("Please input the next positive integer ");
    x = myScanner.nextInt();
  }

  int average = sum / number;

  System.out.println("The average is " + average);
  System.out.println("The minimum value is " + min);
  System.out.print("and the maximum value is " + max);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number=0; //number is to store number of inputs 
    int i=1; //i is to store current iteration
    int sum=0; //sum is to store sum of the input 
    int x=0; //x is to store the user input
    int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE, max=Integer.MIN_VALUE; 

        while (true){
        System.out.println("Please input the next positive integer");
        x = myScanner.nextInt();
        if(x>=0) {
            sum = sum + x;
            number++;
            if (x >= max)
               max = x;
            if (x <= min)
               min =x;
         }
         else 
            break;
       } 
    int average =0;
    if(number >0 ) 
        average = sum/number;
    System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    System.out.println("The minimum value is " + min);
    System.out.print( "and the maximum value is " + max);
    }
```

I have made corrections to your code. This should work. I have removed some redundant code. I think it should work even then.

Comment: It works up until i input a negative number, prompts me with "build failed."

Comment: How could the build fail in the middle of program execution?  That makes no sense.

Comment: The exact thing it tells me is, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"

Comment: @F.ochoa15 this has nothing to do with build - it's a runtime error caused by negative input.

Comment: @F.ochoa15 A miss in the corner case. Please check now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @samdjava, i tried it with your updated code and it works now but still the average and minimum are coming out incorrect. I input, 1,2,3,4,5 as integers, average comes out as 0, min as 0, but max as 5?

Comment: @F.ochoa15 Check now. I had copied your code but overlooked number++. ++ is post increment operator. What it does is first it assigns the value and then it updates the value by adding 1. So it is always levelling to 0.

Comment: Wow, this works the only thing i would need to do is add a command to ask user to input first integer.

Comment: Got it! Is there anyway you could simplify an explanation as to why my original code didn't work and this does? I'd love to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: You can change the print statement to accept numbers generically. In other words do not have two types of statement for accepting first integer or rest of other integer. Few things you should keep in mind while coding.
a. Naming variables.
b. Using less number of conditions.
c. And checking for corner cases. (infact I missed couple of them).

Lets chat over this if you have more questions. Kindly accept the answer.